# Round textbox value to whole number

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 textbox which basically multiply the textbox1 value to textbox2 value then result will be display in a label caption.

So when textbox1 value = 135,55 and textbox2 value is 5
label caption is 67,775.

My problem is, i wanted to make the result value to a whole number.

Example:

```
67,775 result 68,000
67,700 result 68,000
67,500 result 6800

67,499 result 67,000
67,400 result 67000
```

My current code for the label is below.

```
Label1 = Format(Label1, "0,000")
```

Can anyone guide me on how to round up those result value?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Did you check...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function?

Comment: How are you populating these values? Do you need the displayed value to be rounded or do you want the actual value in the textbox to be rounded? Is there any other code behind this? A couple different ways to manage it depending on your execution of the calculation.

Comment: Yes. I want to be the result value to rounded.

Answer (score 0):

I am from a country which uses “.” for decimal and “,” for separator.  I deduce you are from a country that uses “.” and “,” the other way around.

You show us some example results:

```
67,775 result 68,000
67,700 result 68,000
67,500 result 6800

67,499 result 67,000
67,400 result 67000
```

Are `67,500 result 6800` and `67,400 result 67000` typographical errors because I cannot achieve these results.

I can achieve your objective with:

```
Label1 = Format(Round(TextBox1 * TextBox2), "#.##0")
```

In "#.##0", I am using “.” as a separator which I believe you do.